# How to find a string not containing specific word in x-lines

Tags: regex, yaml

I have a lot of json files and inside tags like

```
actions:
    - name: email
      template: email_exp_csr_008
      schedule:
       week: false
       workdays: true
       persistent: true
```

I need to find situation where "schedule:" IS NOT following by "workdays:" within 3 next lines. The above example should not be matched but this one should:

```
actions:
    - name: email
      template: email_exp_csr_008
      schedule:
       week: false
       persistent: true
       werwer: True
```

I tried like this

```
schedule:(.*\n){0,3}.*[^(workdays)]
```

but it does not do the trick. Can anyone help please?

Comment: I removed the JS tag and added yaml. Please re-tag if you need

Comment: Please specify which language you want use to parse the YAML by regex (regex flavors are different among languages/engines) . Depending on the language we also might suggest better tools to solve your task.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the line with `schedule:`, and `workdays:` should not be in the first 3 following lines:

```
^[^\S\n]*schedule:(?!(?:\n[^\S\n]*\w+:.*){0,2}\n[^\S\n]*workdays:)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/72lGlc/1).

If you want to also match the following 0-3 lines:

```
 ^[^\S\n]*schedule:(?!(?:\n[^\S\n]*\w+:.*){0,2}\n[^\S\n]*workdays:)(?:\n[^\S\n]*\w+:.*){0,3}
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/SpCzkI/1).

---

If you want to match the line with `schedule:`, and `workdays:` should not be in the next lines with the same indenting (leading spaces):

```
^([^\S\n]*)schedule:(?!(?:\n\1[^\S\n]*\w+:.*)*\n\1[^\S\n]*workdays:)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/M8fLdb/1).